# c++ handle some word with **array?

Tags: c++

I have some word to handle during my work.

At frist time, i Handle 1~2 word like

```
if (strcmp(d_name, "abc") == 0) {            
        continue;
    }
if (strcmp(d_name, "def") == 0) {            
        continue;
    }
```

but now i have more than 10 words to handle.

so I am trying to find to make char array? list? something...

```
exceptions {"abc", "def", "xyz", ...}

if (strcmp(d_name, exceptions) == 0) {            
        continue;
    }
```

I hope to find this kind of work. is there any good way to me?

Comment: There are no exceptions in this code. I think you are confusing terminology. You should try to explain what you are trying to do, without using the word exceptions in this context.

Comment: @PaulRooney i confused with exception.. and Johnson's answer was what i want to do.. sorry for lack explain..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array of strings;

```
char **excepts = {"abc", "def", "xyz", ..., ""}; // end with ""

bool found=false;
for(int i=0; excepts[i][0]; i++)
{
    if (strcmp(d_name, exceptions) == 0) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(found) continue;
```